# A very small suggestion - rename language agnostic tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I don't know if I should open a question for this or post a comment [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31275/what-does-language-agnostic-mean). So, I will do both anyway. I understand what the Language agnostic tag means. But, those who don't have English as their first language might not understand it. Can we rename it to Any-Language ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the same thing. "language-agnostic" means that the programming language [is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) [irrelevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956478/understanding-randomness). An "any-language" tag, were it to exist, implies that the OP would welcome answers in any language the responder chooses, where "language-agnostic" implies (to me, at least) that a solution in a particular language might not even be required.

Comment: And even then, people who don't understand the tag can mouse over it to see an extended description.